# Pairs of infinite graphs that are minors of each other

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, order-theory, graph-minors

A graph $H$ is a minor of another graph $G$ if $H$ can be obtained from $G$ by deleting edges or vertices and contracting edges.

On finite graphs, the graph minor is a partial order $\preceq$. But this is not true on infinite graphs. Consider for example the square lattice graph $G$ (see below) and let the graph $H$ be the one where we delete all edges in every second “column” and “row”.

[image]

Then $G \preceq H \preceq G$ but $G \neq H$ and so the partial order is not antisymmetric.

Is anything known about such counterexamples, do they have a name? Do they have characterisation when $G$ is a lattice graph?

Comment: This specific graph is sometimes called a grid minor, however I do not know if there is a name for the class of infinite graphs that break the partial order. The paper "Excluding a full grid minor" by Karl Heuer characterizes when a graph has a $\mathbb Z\times\mathbb Z$ grid minor. But obviously there are infinite graphs that don't have $\mathbb Z\times\mathbb Z$ as a minor but still break the partial order.